# 2x2 columns in a latex Beamer

Tags: beamer, overleaf, columns, frame

I am trying to get 2 sets of 2 columns in a latex Beamer, but of 2 kinds. I’d need the first one to be ~0.7 & ~0.3 wide and the second ~ 0.5 and ~0.5 wide. This is what I’ve done. It works for 2 columns only perfectly, but completely breaks down for 2 sets of 2 columns in one frame.

I’d appreciate any help!

```
\begin{frame}{Production and decay modes}
  \framesubtitle{\insertsubsectionhead}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
    Figure X: Higgs production channels
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{higgs_production_channels.png}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Production.pdf.png}
    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
    \caption{Higgs production channels}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}  %%<--- here
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Branching.pdf}
     \captionsetup{justification=centering}
     \caption{Higgs production channels}
     \end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: How does the output you get look like and what specifically do you not like about it? If I make your code compilable, at first glance the output looks as expected.

Comment: It was just all red, but I somehow made it work. I stopped the compilation and then compiled it again and it works now :) thanks!